# Re-partition without damaging backup set

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, partition

I have an eight-terabyte powered drive formatted as follows:

```
/dev/disk12 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 TB     disk12
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk12s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Seagate 3TB             3.0 TB     disk12s2
                    (free space)                         134.2 MB   -
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk13        5.0 TB     disk12s3

/dev/disk13 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +5.0 TB     disk13
                                 Physical Store disk12s3
   1:                APFS Volume Seagate 5TB             4.0 TB     disk13s2
```

“Seagate 5TB” is a Time Machine backup drive.  “Seagate 3TB” is empty except for `.DS_Store`,`.Spotlight-V100`, & `.fseventsd` which are meaningless on an otherwise empty volume.

**If possible, how can I convert it into a single APFS volume with one container and two volumes, merging 3TB and the free space into one volume, with 5TB the other volume, without breaking the backups already in 5TB?**

If necessary (and possible), I could copy the backup set to an empty 5TB physical drive and copy it back.  But I’d rather not, because that would take a LONG time (5TB is already 4TB used).

I think I would also need to set quotas, to change 5TB to 6 TB or less and 3TB to 2 TB or less (renaming both).

I do not trust the [AI-generated answer](https://www.perplexity.ai/search/An-eightterabyte-powered-DaMF_VGKTLCcJNQ9xNUyFg) that tells me to backup the backup and then erase.  :-)

Comment: Your AI answer will preserve data on the 3TB, but zap the 5TB.

Comment: AI stands for “Artificial Idiocy”. (It seems these AIs are programmed never to give you no answer. I would have answered “not a clue” but the AI want allowed to. )